# how to transfer a video (or any other media) from an iphone to a windows phone, without using internet

Tags: lumia-520

Is it possible to transfer any media from an iphone to a windows phone without using internet?

Comment: Is the media DRM-protected? Can you use a PC as an intermediary?

Answer (score 2):

Without internet connection, there are only few ways to transfer video from Iphone to Windows phone.

1. Bluetooth - Not supported by Iphone since Iphone bluetooth will work only with apple devices.
2. PC - Copy the video from Iphone to PC using iTunes. Again from PC to Windows phone.

I guess 2nd is the only option as on now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of these 3 windows phone and Iphone apps:

Feem

- Windows Store : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/feem-v4-share-files-offline/9wzdncrdsfg0
- Itunes : https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/feem-v4-share-files-offline/id1046483430?ls=1&mt=8

SHARE.it

- Windows Store : https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/p/shareit/9wzdncrdsz0p
- Itunes : https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/shareit-connect-transfer/id725215120?mt=8

Easy Transfer

- Windows store : https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/p/easy-transfer/9wzdncrfhzq8

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that You don't want to use PC, You can upload files to cloud storage from one device (OneDrive/Google Drive/Dropbox and so on) and download them on another. If You don't want to use internet connection either, you can send files through MMS.

Comment: That wont work without internet.

Comment: i don't want to take any option involving internet connections, would you please modify your answer based on question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to share the media, you can try to share it via Bluetooth. Make sure Bluetooth is on on both devices.

Comment: Ha. Have fun. iPhones can't Bluetooth to non-iOS devices.

Comment: this is sad... typical apple.